# Predefined type 'System.void' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, types, mono

I've installed Xamarin Studio Community a few minutes ago (on a windows 7 machine). Now I was trying to create a simple library in c# (target framework Mono/ .Net 4.0), but Xamarin Studios intellisense tells me that the "Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported". Well, the system/ system.core/ system.data and system.security assemblies are referenced. Is it possible that my installation of Xamarin Studio is broken?

The build log is also useless. Here's it's output
(As you can see there aren't further informations why the build process failed):

Erzeuge Projektmappe (Build projectmap): WinEasy.Backend (Debug)

--------------------- Fertig (Done) ---------------------

Erstellen fehlgeschlagen. (Failed to build)
Build: 1 Fehler (1 error), 0 Warnungen (0 warnings)

---

After all I can say that the upgrade from xamarin studio 5.10 → 6.0 is the reason for my problem. With version 5.10 it works!

Comment: I would recommend that you use Visual Studio on Windows and Xamarin Studio on Mac. Can you try Visual Studio on Windows and see if you run into the same issues?

Comment: I'm using VS since a few years now.. There's really no need for Xamarin Studio, but since I'm really astonished from it's design I would really give it a try